# How to navigate a view to subview in a buttonclick?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii.I have added a subview by using interface of the main view,and i insert some controls in the subview,i add outlet for this subview,the problem is i want to navigate this subview from the main-view by button click.
How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this application navigation based?

Comment: @iApple Yeaa its a navigation based appliaction

Comment: Has the subview its separate xib?

Comment: @Nipin Varma: You mean you want to navigate the subview not the main view? and what is frame size of the subview?

Comment: @iApple the frame size is 320/480 ,i want to navigate to subview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate from subview in a navigation based application...(subView1 is an instance of your suubview)

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:subview1 animated:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your second class in .m file then,
In the method of button click event write following code, where ClassName is the name of second class in which you want to navigate.

```
ClassName *cls = [[ClassName alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClassName" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController cls animated:NO];
    [cls release];
```